# What vampire movie is this?

Tags: story-identification, movie, vampire

- A guy is chosen to be the next Dracula, but he resists by trying to drink holy water and doing other things to resist. Eventually, he loses his reflection in the mirror;
- A girl helps this guy to resist becoming a vampire, but herself *wants to be a vampire* to gain eternal life;
- The vampire is using a building which is guarded by a demon (with security uniform). All the vampires sleep during the day inside that building in individual coffins;
- The vampires party every night;
- Every time when vampire capture victims, they suck the blood and give the flesh and bone for demon food;
- Two cops/police/sheriff die and their body is missing after they are assigned to check the vampire building, and those two cops/police/sheriff become vampires too;
- A guy comes to the vampire base during the daytime kills the demon guard by hanging him with a rope.
- The guy enters the vampire base and kills the vampires all one-by-one, opening one coffin after another.
- The girl becomes a vampire and helps the hero.
- The final Dracula was killed with a bow and arrow because the hero has run out of stakes after killing so many vampires.

Some background: I saw this on TV in English, 2003-2010. It's not a Hollywood movie, and it didn't have any famous actors in it that I remember.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using the word "Dracula" but mean "vampire". Was this deliberate? Is he specifically turning into a Dracula?

Comment: Hmm. There are elements here that match [The Lost Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Boys)...

Comment: Where did you watch this? In what language? Was it a "Hollywood" movie? When was it set? Can you remember any actors' names?

Comment: i watch this on local nation tv channel, in english, not a Hollywood movie, it set on 2003 - 2010, i can't remember any actor name... no one is famous...

Comment: Can you remember any details form [lists here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)? Anything would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mind specifying what your local nation is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sound to me like it's [**Vampires: Out for Blood**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0375562/) (2004)

> *Police Officer Hank Holten (Kevin Dillon) is obsessed with his soon to be ex-wife, vampire novelist Susan Hastings. He follows her around and eventually gets reprimanded by his superior Captain Billings played by horror legend Lance Henriksen. While on an undercover assignment he goes to an underground vampire coven that throws parties, sets up orgies then they pounce on their victims. Hank is lured in by the smoking hot Layla (Jodi Lyn O’Keefe) to go to the party. Once in the throes of passion he is attacked. He fights them off and escapes but not before he is bit by the hideously deformed main vampire. He eventually teams up with his ex-wife trying to figure out once and for all how to defeat the vampires, stop himself from turning, while dealing with Layla and other vampires who are trying to welcome him into the family.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Horrorphilia: Vampires: Out For Blood (2004) Movie Review](https://www.horrorphilia.com/vampires-out-for-blood-2004-movie-review/)</sup></sub>

Comment: this is the best anwer

Comment: 14 years looking for the title of this movie

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Dracula III: The Legacy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303929/?ref_=nv_sr_1) from 2005?

It starred Jason Scott Lee and Rutger Hauer as Dracula and had a woman becoming a vampire and helping the heroes.

I remember the main hero **becoming a vampire and trying to resist it.**

Comment: The story was similar, but this movie don't have any castle